# Sort pagniation by relationship count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to sort question by the amount of their answers (one to many relationship).
`orderBy` just works for columns, but in this case I need to sort by a value.

```
SELECT
  answers.question_id,
  count(*) AS Counter
FROM answers, questions
WHERE answers.id = questions.id
WHERE question.year > 2014
GROUP BY answers.question_id
ORDER BY `Counter` DESC
```

How can I use laravel's pagnation here?

```
$questions->where('year', '>', 2014)
    ->paginate(10)
```

Will do pagnation, but not sorting the results.

SortBy is no solution, because then I need to get all results, sorting them and then picking only 10. It's a huge time waste.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the power of [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) !
Assusming you have correctly set up your models.

```
$questions = Question::with('answers')->get()->sortBy(function($question) {
    return $question->answers->count();
});
```

Will return a collection of Questions sorted by the number of answers. With this you can manually build a [Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) object like so (since the `paginate` method can only be used on Eloquent objects) :

```
$questions = new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($questions, 10);
// 10 being the number of results per page.
```

Comment: I thought about that, but he mentions that sortBy on a collection is not a solution since you have to load all the results.

Comment: Pagination works this way in Laravel, if you don't want to load all the results I suggest limiting them manually with `take` and `skip` methods. But I don't think you can benefit of the Pagination without loading every results.

Answer (score -1):

You should be looking at `whereHas()`, which allows you to put a where clause on your relationship.

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%

$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
})->get();
```

And then, in your case you can run `paginate()` instead of `get()` to get the `LenghtAwarePaginator` Object.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with sorting items.

Comment: I dont't wand to order my relationchips, i want to count them and then order by the counted values,